# Redirect urls of a blog - htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

my questions are simple, how can I redirect this kind of urls :

www.domain.com/?page_id=25&ID=46
to : 
www.anotherdomain.com/

When I try with this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:anotherdomain.com\" [R=301,L]
```

The url is redirected to http:anotherdomain.com\?page_id=25&ID=46

And another redirection I need is to redirect this :

blog1.domain.com to anotherdomain.com knowing that there are multiple blocks.

Thanks for any help,
Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|blog1)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.anotherdomain.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: When I try your code, all the domain.com is redirected to anotherdomain.com

Comment: @Skumbabs Edited the reply above.

Comment: Thanks, it's almost what i need. I have just one more problem, when I just go to domain.com it's redirected to anotherdomain.com. Is it possible to stay ? Thanks very much for your replies.

Comment: Weren't you trying to achieve the same @Skumbabs ?

Comment: In resume I'm trying to redirect blog1.domain.com to anotherdomain.com, it works perfectly with your code but I would like that when I go on the url domain.com (so without a blog prefix) I will be not redirected.

Comment: Replace `^(www|blog1)` part with just `^blog1`

Comment: Thanks this is perfect !